# Prove (transposition)(even permutation)=(odd permutation)

Tags: group-theory

Q. Prove that for even permutation $\tau$ and transposition $\sigma$, if  $\sigma\tau=\rho$, then $\rho$ is odd permutation.


I came up with two ways to solve the problem：

ⅰ)

$\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma\tau)=\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\operatorname{sgn}(\tau)=-1$ so, $\rho$ is odd permutation.

ⅱ)

Since $\tau$ is an even permutation, it can be expressed as a product of an even number of transpositions. $\sigma\tau$ is expressed as a product of an odd number of compatibilities, so $\rho$ is an odd permutation.


However, I feel that the essence of these two proofs are similar. It also seemed to me that when using ii, it is necessary to prove that permutation can be expressed as product of transposition. How can I prove this?


Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can see Herstein's book for the proof that every permutation is a product of transpositions. In fact, as a good thinking exercise you can try to write a few permutations (say of 4 or 5 elements) as a product of transpositions.

Comment: What is your definition of even permutation?

Answer (score 1):

We will prove that $(a_1,a_2,a_3,...a_n)$=$(a_1,a_n)(a_1,a_{n-1})...(a_1,a_2)$. Just observe which element each element will be send to. We analyze $(a_1,a_n)(a_1,a_{n-1})...(a_1,a_2)$.

$a_1\xrightarrow{\text{($a_1,a_2$)}}a_2\xrightarrow{\text{($a_1,a_3$)}}a_2\xrightarrow{\text{($a_1,a_4$)}}a_2...\xrightarrow{\text{($a_1,a_n$)}}a_2$

So $a_1$ will be send to $a_2$ by the transpositions $(a_1,a_n)(a_1,a_{n-1})...(a_1,a_2)$. Similarly,

$a_2\xrightarrow{\text{($a_1,a_2$)}}a_1\xrightarrow{\text{($a_1,a_3$)}}a_3\xrightarrow{\text{($a_1,a_4$)}}a_3...\xrightarrow{\text{($a_1,a_n$)}}a_3$

$a_3\xrightarrow{\text{($a_1,a_2$)}}a_3\xrightarrow{\text{($a_1,a_3$)}}a_1\xrightarrow{\text{($a_1,a_4$)}}a_4...\xrightarrow{\text{($a_1,a_n$)}}a_2$

. . . 

$a_n\xrightarrow{\text{($a_1,a_2$)}}a_n\xrightarrow{\text{($a_1,a_3$)}}a_n\xrightarrow{\text{($a_1,a_4$)}}a_n...\xrightarrow{\text{($a_1,a_n$)}}a_1$

So each $a_i$ is sent to $a_{i+1}$ for $i<n$, and $a_n$ is sent to $a_1$. This is exactly the permutation $(a_1,a_2,a_3,...a_n)$. Thus, any permutation, which might be a product of several shorter permutations, can be rewritten as products of transpositions simply by rewriting each of its components (i.e, the shorter permutations that it's composed of) into transpositions.